# exercise #40 in A Tour of Go

Tags: go

My quick searching did not reveal anyone sharing their solution to [this exercise](http://tour.golang.org/#40), so am not sure if there are other (and better) approaches to mine:

```
package main

import (
    "code.google.com/p/go-tour/wc"
    "strings"
)

func WordCount(s string) map[string]int {
    foo := strings.Fields(s)
    m := make(map[string]int)
    for i := 0; i < len(foo); i++ {
        v, ok := m[foo[i]]
        if ok {
            m[foo[i]] = v + 1
        }
        m[foo[i]] = v + 1
    }
    return m
}

func main() {
    wc.Test(WordCount)
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can be more concise and readable using `range` and the fact that the default value of the int is `0` :

```
func WordCount(s string) map[string]int {
    m := make(map[string]int)
    for _, w := range(strings.Fields(s)) {
        m[w]++
    }
    return m
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Programmers spend almost all their time reading code; code should be documented. API users need good documentation too.

A meaningless name like `foo` is the first red flag; good names are an excellent form of code documentation.

Go has a documentation tool: [Godoc: documenting Go code](http://golang.org/doc/articles/godoc_documenting_go_code.html). "Documentation is a huge part of making software accessible and maintainable."

Here's my solution:

```
// A Tour of Go. Exercise 40: Maps.
package main

import (
    "code.google.com/p/go-tour/wc"
    "strings"
)

// WordCount returns a map of the counts of each “word” in the string s.
func WordCount(s string) map[string]int {
    counts := make(map[string]int)
    for _, word := range strings.Fields(s) {
        counts[word]++
    }
    return counts
}

func main() {
    wc.Test(WordCount)
}
```